# Can FFmpeg output time duration since the start of a job?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way for `FFmpeg` to output or log time duration since a particular job/process was started?

I know that there are more or less complicated ways to display a [progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747982/can-ffmpeg-show-a-progress-bar) which really seems more like a programmatical problem.

The reasoning is that I want to measure how long time my encoding jobs take (without having to set up a separate timer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux you can use the `time` command:

```
$ time ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4
  [...]
  real  0m1.927s
  user  0m7.067s
  sys   0m0.243s
```

This example took 1.927 seconds to complete.

Comment: or you can use `ffmpeg -benchmark -i `
Show benchmarking information at the end of an encode. Shows CPU time used and maximum memory consumption. Maximum memory consumption is not supported on all systems, it will usually display as 0 if not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-benchmark`.
You will see something like `bench: utime=11.969s stime=0.315s rtime=1.908s`, the `rtime` is what you want.

Comment: How do you use this command? I tired ffmpeg.exe -i input.ts -benchmark output.mp4 AS WELL AS ffmpeg.exe -i input.ts output.mp4 -benchmark, non worked

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `-report` option, ffmpeg will create a logfile at initialization and the filename will contain the time at which it was created. You can use the last modified time of the log file to get the completion time, and thus the duration. On Windows, you could just check the creation time of the output as well.

**Addendum**: A rough way to get this information, universally, without altering the command or using a monitoring tool like `time`, as LN guided, is to note the encoding speed normally reported i.e. `speed=5.50x`. So, if the duration of the output file is 110 seconds, then time taken to encode is **110 / 5.5 = 20 seconds**.